# Why my inversions of matrices are such slow with LAPACKE in C++ : MAGMA Alternative and set up

Tags: c++, matrix, lapack, inversion, magma

I am using `LAPACK` to inverse a matrix: I did a reference passing, i.e by working on the address. Here below the function with an input matrix and an output matrix referenced by their address.

The issue is that I am obliged to convert the `F_matrix` into `1D array` and I think this is a waste of performances on the runtime level : which way could I find to get rid of this supplementary task which is time consuming I think if I call a lot of times the
function `matrix_inverse_lapack`.

Below the function concerned :

```
// Passing Matrixes by Reference
void matrix_inverse_lapack(vector<vector<double>> const &F_matrix, vector<vector<double>> &F_output) {

  // Index for loop and arrays
  int i, j, ip, idx;

  // Size of F_matrix
  int N = F_matrix.size();

  int *IPIV = new int[N];

  // Statement of main array to inverse
  double *arr = new double[N*N];

  // Output Diagonal block
  double *diag = new double[N];

for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<N; j++){
      idx = i*N + j;
      arr[idx] = F_matrix[i][j];
    }
  }

  // LAPACKE routines
  int info1 = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, arr, N, IPIV);
  int info2 = LAPACKE_dgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, arr, N, IPIV);

 for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<N; j++){
      idx = i*N + j;
      F_output[i][j] = arr[idx];
    }
  }

  delete[] IPIV;
  delete[] arr;
}
```

For example, I call it this way :

```
vector<vector<double>> CO_CL(lsize*(2*Dim_x+Dim_y), vector<double>(lsize*(2*Dim_x+Dim_y), 0));

... some code

matrix_inverse_lapack(CO_CL, CO_CL);
```

The performances on inversion are not which are expected, I think this is due to this conversion `2D -> 1D` that I described in the function `matrix_inverse_lapack`.

### Update

I was advised to install MAGMA on my MacOS Big Sur 11.3 but I have a lot of difficulties to set up it.

I have a `AMD Radeon Pro 5600M` graphic card. I have already installed by default Big Sur version all the Framework OpenCL (maybe I am wrong by saying that). Anyone could tell the procedure to follow for the installation of MAGMA. I saw that on a MAGMA software exists on http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/ but it is really expensive and doesn't correspond to what I want : I just need all the SDK (headers and libraries) , if possible built with my GPU card. I have already installed all the Intel OpenAPI SDK on my MacOS. Maybe, I could link it to a MAGMA installation.

I saw another link https://icl.utk.edu/magma/software/index.html where MAGMA seems to be public : there is none link with the non-free version above, isn't there ?

Comment: Maybe try with CUBLAS or MAGMA if LAPACK is slow.

Comment: @ÖöTiib . Thanks for your quick answer. Do you know a link or a well known example of MAGMA in my case ? , that is to say, easy to implement instead of my LAPACKE function ? Regards

Comment: this tutorial has examples https://ecpannualmeeting.com/assets/overview/sessions/2020-magma-heffte-tutorial.pdf

Comment: @ÖöTiib. I have installed a few days ago the Intel SDK OneAPI. Can Magma be integrated with Intel SDK OneAPI ?

Comment: Two things that are open source can be integrated. What are the alleged difficulties?

Comment: @ÖöTiib . I tried to install `clmagma-1.3.0` since I have a `AMD Radeon Pro 5600M` graphic card. I think that I can't install classical `MAGMA  2.5.4` because I have not NVIDIA Cuda card. Moreover, I am on MacOS Big Sure 11.3, it seems to make things more complicated. Have you got informations or links about this ? Best regards

Comment: With MacOS it can be really rough I avoid it for that kind of works.

Comment: @ÖöTiib . I agree, it is very difficult to install `MAGMA` and `clmagma` under MacOS (in my case Big Sure 11.3). I am surely be obliged to take the non-free version by downloading the `.dmg`. Could anyone manage to install the free versions ?

Comment: What makes  you think "The performances on inversion are not which are expected"? What did you expect and what can you actually see in terms of performance? Can you give some examples of the sizes of matrices you use? 10? 100? 1000? The larger the matrices, the smaller effect of 2D->1D->2D  conversion will be. Have you performed any benchmarks? If so, can you share the results?

Comment: I am using sizes between 100 and 1000, it may vary but this is the common range. Actually, I thought that I was doing only LAPACKE on CPU power, and given the fact that I have a 8Gb graphic card, I wondered how to use it to make matrices inversion with GPU power instead of CPU. Can SDK Intel OneAPI allow to use my GPU card instead of only CPU. The problem is that I have a MacBook pro with `Intel CPU` but a `AMD Radeon Pro 5600M` : so I guess it is going to be difficult to use LAPACK with a `AMD GPU` card.

Comment: that's why I think about `MAGMA` that could **allow to make matrix inversion** with `GPU card`. What do you think about all of that ? Best regards

Comment: Well. Please decide what is your problem/question. As I understood your wording, you thought Lapack is slow because of conversion 2D->1D->2D. My answer below explains that it is not an issue. If you are looking for a more powerful/efficient linear algebra library, than this is a completely different question! It is also possible that inverting a matrix is only a tool and that you can achieve your true goal, whatever it is, more efficiently in a different way, by algorithmic changes.

Comment: @zkoza . apologies. I didn't think there was a significant latency if I use GPU libraries instead of CPU LAPACKE only. This is a problem of performance and optimisation. I will take into account of all your remarks and tests that you gave below

Comment: I added a small section on other alternative libraries. I like Plasma, but as I said, I have not used any of lin alg libraries for several years. Also: on my computer it takes 1 ms to invert a 100 by 100 matrix (CPU, single thread).   In this case an extra latency of a few microseconds should be acceptable. However, a few years ago I was *very* serious about linear algebra on GPU and the conclusion was that latency + 2-way communication would kill all the speed-up, unless you ported everything to GPU. Hence my scepticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let me complain that OP did not provide all necessary data. The program is *almost* complete, but it is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is important because (a) it wastes time and (b) it hides potentially relevant information, eg. about the matrix initialization. Second, OP did not provide any details on the compilation, which, again may be relevant.
Last, but not least, OP didn't check the status code for possible errors from Lapack functions, and this could also be important for correct interpretation of the results.

Let's start from a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Matrix const &v)
{
    const auto size = std::min<int>(10, v.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            out << v[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        if (size < std::ssize(v)) out << "...";
        out << "\n";
    }
    return out;
}

void matrix_inverse_lapack(Matrix const &F_matrix, Matrix &F_output, std::vector<int> &IPIV_buffer,
                           std::vector<double> &matrix_buffer)
{
    //  std::cout << F_matrix << "\n";
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    const int N = F_matrix.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            auto idx = i * N + j;
            matrix_buffer[idx] = F_matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // LAPACKE routines
    int info1 = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, matrix_buffer.data(), N, IPIV_buffer.data());
    int info2 = LAPACKE_dgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, matrix_buffer.data(), N, IPIV_buffer.data());
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            auto idx = i * N + j;
            F_output[i][j] = matrix_buffer[idx];
        }
    }
    auto t3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto whole_fun_time = std::chrono::duration<double>(t3 - t0).count();
    auto lapack_time = std::chrono::duration<double>(t2 - t1).count();
    //   std::cout << F_output << "\n";
    std::cout << "status: " << info1 << "\t" << info2 << "\t" << (info1 == 0 && info2 == 0 ? "Success" : "Failure")
              << "\n";
    std::cout << "whole function:            " << whole_fun_time << "\n";
    std::cout << "LAPACKE matrix operations: " << lapack_time << "\n";
    std::cout << "conversion:                " << (whole_fun_time - lapack_time) / whole_fun_time * 100.0 << "%\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const int M = 5;  // numer of test repetitions

    const int N = (argc > 1) ? std::stoi(argv[1]) : 10;
    std::cout << "Matrix size = " << N << "\n";

    std::vector<int> IPIV_buffer(N);
    std::vector<double> matrix_buffer(N * N);

    // Test matrix_inverse_lapack M times
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        Matrix CO_CL(N);
        for (auto &v : CO_CL) v.resize(N);

        int idx = 1;
        for (auto &v : CO_CL)
        {
            for (auto &x : v)
            {
                x = idx + 1.0 / idx;
                idx++;
            }
        }
        matrix_inverse_lapack(CO_CL, CO_CL, IPIV_buffer, matrix_buffer);
    }
}
```

Here, `operator<<` is an overkill, but may be useful for anyone wanting to verify half-manually that the code works (by uncommenting lines 26 and 58), and ensuring that the code is correct is more important that measuring its performance.

The code can be compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O3  main.cpp -llapacke
```

The program relies on an external library, `lapacke`,  which needs to be installed, headers + binaries, for the code to compile and run.

My code differs a bit from OP's: it is closer to "modern C++" in that it refrains from using naked pointers; I also added external buffers to `matrix_inverse_lapack` to suppress continual launching of memory allocator and deallocator, a small improvement that reduces the 2D-1D-2D conversion overhead in a measurable way. I also had to initialize the matrix and find a way to read in OP's mind what the value of `N` could be. I also added some timer readings for benchmarking. Apart from this, the logic of the code is unchanged.

Now a benchmark carried out on a decent workstation. It lists the percentage of time the conversion takes relative to the total time taken by `matrix_inverse_lapack`. In other words, I measure the conversion overhead:

```
 N =   10, 3.5%   
 N =   30, 1.5%   
 N =  100, 1%   
 N =  300, 0.5%   
 N = 1000, 0.35%  
 N = 3000, 0.1%
```

The time taken by Lapack nicely scales as N<sup>3</sup>, as expected (data not shown). The time to invert a matrix is about 16 seconds for N = 3000, and about 5<sup>-6</sup> s (5 microseconds) for N = 10.

I assume the overhead of even 3% is completely acceptable. I believe OP uses matrices of size larger then 100, in which case the overhead at or below 1% is certainly acceptable.

So what OP (or anyone having a similar problem) could have done wrong to obtain "unacceptable overhead conversion values"? Here's my short list

1. Improper compilation
2. Improper matrix initialization (for tests)
3. Improper benchmarking

***1. Improper compilation***

If one forgets to compile in Release mode, one ends up with optimized Lapacke competing with unoptimized conversion. On my machine this peaks at an 33% overhead for N = 20.

***2. Improper matrix initialization (for tests)***

If one initializes the matrix like this:

```
        for (auto &v : CO_CL)
        {
            for (auto &x : v)
            {
                x = idx; // rather than, eg., idx + 1.0/idx
                idx++;
            }
        }
```

then the matrix is singular, lapack returns quite quickly with the status different from 0. This increases the relative importance of the conversion part. But singular matrices are not what one wants to invert (it's impossible to do).

***3. Improper benchmarking***

Here's an example of the program output for N = 10:

```
 ./a.out 10 
 Matrix size = 10
 status: 0  0   Success
 whole function:            0.000127658
 LAPACKE matrix operations: 0.000126783
 conversion:                0.685425%
 status: 0  0   Success
 whole function:            1.2497e-05
 LAPACKE matrix operations: 1.2095e-05
 conversion:                3.21677%
 status: 0  0   Success
 whole function:            1.0535e-05
 LAPACKE matrix operations: 1.0197e-05
 conversion:                3.20835%
 status: 0  0   Success
 whole function:            9.741e-06
 LAPACKE matrix operations: 9.422e-06
 conversion:                3.27482%
 status: 0  0   Success
 whole function:            9.939e-06
 LAPACKE matrix operations: 9.618e-06
 conversion:                3.2297%
```

One can see that the first call to lapack functions can take 10 times more time than the subsequent calls. This is quite a stable pattern, as if Lapack needed some time for self-initialization. It can affect the measurements for small N badly.

***4. What else can be done?***

OP apperas to believe that his approach to 2D arrays is good and Lapack is strange and old-fashionable in its packing a 2D array into a 1D array. No. It is Lapack who is right.

If one defines a 2D array as `vector<vector<double>>`, one obtains one advantage: code simplicity. This comes at a price. Each row of such a matrix is allocated separateley from the others. Thus, a matrix 100 by 100 may be stored in 100 completely different memory blocks. This has a bad impact on the cache (and prefetcher) utilization. Lapck (and other linear algebra packages) enforces compactification of the data in a single, continuous array. This is so to minimize cache and prefetcher misses. If OP had used such an approach from the very beginning, he would probably have gained more than 1-3% that they pay now for the conversion.

This compactification can be achieved in at least three ways.

- Write a custom class for a 2D matrix, with the internal data stored in a 1D array and convenient access member funnctions (e.g.: `operator ()`), or find a library that does just that
- Write a custom allocator for `std::vector` (or find a library). This allocator should allocate the memory from a preallocated 1D vector exactly matching the data storage pattern used by Lapack
- Use `std::vector<double*>` and initailze the pointers with the addresses pointing at the appropriate elements of a preallocated 1D array.

Each of the above solutions forces some changes to the surrounding code, which OP might not want to do. All depends on the code complexity and expected performance gains.

***EDIT: Alternative libraries***

An alternative approach is to use a library that is *known* for being a highly optimzed one. Lapack by itself can be regardered as a standard interface with many implementations and it may happen that OP uses an unoptimized one. Which library to choose may depend on the  hardware/software platform OP is interested in and may vary in time.

As for now  (mid-2021) a decent suggestions are:

- Lapack https://www.netlib.org/lapack/
- Atlas  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software  http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/
- OpenBlas https://www.openblas.net/
- Magma https://developer.nvidia.com/magma
- Plasma https://bitbucket.org/icl/plasma/src/main/

If OP uses martices of sizes at least 100, then GPU-oriented MAGMA might be worth trying.

An easier (installation, running) way might with a parallel CPU library, e.g. Plasma. Plsama is Lapack-compliant, it has been being developed by a large team of people, including Jack Dongarra, it also  should be rather easy to compile it locally as it is provided with a CMake script.

An example how much a parallel CPU-based, multicore implementation can outperform a single-threaded implementation of the LU-decomposition can be found for example here: https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/miller/Courses/CSE633/Tummala-Spring-2014-CSE633.pdf (short answer: 5 to 15 times for matrices of size 1000).

Comment: Thanks for your detailled answer. I am going to read it again deeper. Best regards

Comment: Oh, forget about the `template`. I experimented a bit with other definitions of Matrix, but realized it would be too time-consuming for me to get deep into it. I'll edit it out.

Comment: just a detail, why don't you use `using namespace std;`  at the begin of your solutions ? , this would alleviate the notations

Comment: I am going to bore you again : could you take a look at my **UPDATE** when I talk about the `MAGMA` library in order to use GPU for matrix inversion ? Any advise is welcome.

Comment: I don't know MAGMA, but I doubt GPU can be utilized in accordance with its massively parallel architecture to invert dense matrices. A typical algorithm for the LU factorisation is intrinsically sequential.  On the other hand, one can solve `Ax = y` for `x` without computing the inverse of A using, for example, Krylov-space methods (designed for large, sparse matrices) quite efficiently on GPUs.  So, a lot depends on the context: what do you need the inverse of A for, how big it is, how often the same matrix is being used and how often it s to be reassembled. A universal answer doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, as for GPUS, remember they have a large latency. They are external devices to  CPUs, hence the latency. A few years ago the latency was a few microseconds. If the matrices are small and must be often reassembled on the CPU, the latency kills any speedup offered by the GPU once it has read all the necessary data. Again: all depends on the context.

Comment: Another sensitive problem with GPUs is that using them efficiently may require porting most of the code to the GPU (usually highly nontrivial) to minimize the communication latency, and using GPU's architecture efficiently  may require to rewrite the data structures in the already existing CPU code:  CPU  is designed to minimize / hide any memory-access-related latency, while GPU is designed with an assumption that you feed it with large, continuous data streams.